# How to change parameter visibility when accessing the report from Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, visibility, reportmanager

I am working on reports in SSRS 2008 (not R2)... There are some reports with parameters that are hidden when the report is accessed through normal URL using ReportViewer.asx

The thing is that these hidden parameters need to be visible when the report is accessed using SSRS Report Manager.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can leave the parameters visible in the report and point a linked report to it.   Hide any parameters in the linked report, and point ReportViewer to the linked report.   You can manage who can see the base report on Report Manager with permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the parameters as visible on the server. You can't change their visibility on the fly from the URL. However, in the ReportViewer control you can provide a value for the parameter and hide it. You call the `SetParameters` method and pass a `ReportParameter` object (or a list of them) to specify parameter values. `ReportParameter` has a constructor override whose third argument is `bool visible`.

This will give the parameter a value and hide it in the report viewer control:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ParameterName","ParameterValue",false))
```

If you don't want to provide a value, you need to build the `ReportParameter` object first with just the `Name` and `Visible` properties and then pass to `SetParameters`. Like so:

```
var parm = new ReportParameter();

parm.Name = "ParameterName";
parm.Visible = false;

ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parm);
```

Comment: That sound like it will work... I'll try it right away... thanks!!

Comment: One question... what if I don't want to set a value for the parameters, but stick with the value that is being sent in the URL? Can I just ommit the value part, like
`ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ParameterName",,false))`

Comment: You can't omit a parameter in the constructor, but you could construct the `ReportParameter` ahead of time with just the name and visible properties and try passing that. I'm not sure whether it will work, though.

Comment: Or maybe you could use the `GetParameters` method first and get the default value for that parameter and use it.